# wxWidgets GUI issue

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

I just updated wxWidgets from 2.8.12 to 2.9.4. I built all the libraries like before and compiled by program. There are a couple of issues that I'm getting.

1) I get this after compilation: [image]

2) When I click cancel, my GUI is greyed out like so: [image]

The grey bar on the top and bottom are toolbars that usually have a blue gradient as the background on Windows. Also, the buttons have a dark stroked border as well.

Just wondering if anyone has come across this? One thing of note, I'm using MSVC and am using the debug libraries in vc_lib. Everything seems to work well on 2.8.12 if I revert back. I would really appreciate some feedback.

3) 2.8.12 screenshot (normal): [image]

Answer (score 3):

The assert indicates a problem in your code: you're using more than one mode when creating `wxListCtrl`. You simply need to fix this.

The rest of the problem is less clear, perhaps you should show how does the same UI look when built with wxWidgets 2.8.

Comment: Added the 2.8 screenshot. As you can see, it's all normal. As for the wxListCtrl, the style I have set is wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, so I don't know what to do about that.

Comment: wxListCtrl does not have wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE flag (see the documentation http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_list_ctrl.html). wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE is a flag from wxFrame class (see the documentation http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_frame.html) and may override 2 or more mode flags of wxListCtrl. Agree with VZ at this point.